# How to use Redux with React class component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I am trying to use Redux with React Class (typescript), according to this [tutorial](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/usage-with-typescript#typing-the-connect-higher-order-component). But I have so many compilation errors that I don't even know where to start. Obviously I'm doing something wrong. Can you please provide an implementation and usage example for the following code:

```
type CounterProps = {
  exampleProp: string;
};

type CounterState = {
  exampleState: string;
};

class CounterComponent extends React.Component<CounterProps, CounterState> {
  constructor(props: Readonly<CounterProps> | CounterProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      exampleState: '',
    };
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => {
  return {
    count: state.count,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  incrementCounter,
};

const connector = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CounterComponent);

type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;
```

Comment: Advice: stop using class components and start using functional components with hooks

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the `ConnectedProps<T>` type, you need break the connecting into two steps.  Otherwise you would have a circular type reference (where the connected component types depend on the inner component types, which depend on the connected component types).

First, you create the `connector` HOC, which you can get the types from.

```
const connector = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);

type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;
```

Second, you apply the `connector` to the base component.

```
const ConnectedCounter = connector(CounterComponent);
```

This way the `connector` knows about the types from `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`, but it does not know anything about `CounterComponent`. So it's not cyclical.

---

If you are just learning then you should absolutely learn with function components instead!